# How to prevent lost writes in Parse/Back4app?

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

I couldn't find any support for a CAS operation or a [findAndModify](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.findAndModify) like in MongoDB that could allow me to include a version field in objects and update them only if the retrieved version is the same as the current one in the server, like the [optimistic locking approach in JPA](https://vladmihalcea.com/optimistic-locking-version-property-jpa-hibernate/).

There is some support to do such thing that I missed? Otherwise how we can implement any logic that accepts concurrent access to the same objects from different users?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the Idempotency feature ? Not specifically what you are asking, but might be some logic in there that helps you...

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/6748

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can clarify your question. But I answer your question as I understand it.

MongoDb updates already atomic operations. and Parse Server while updating data,
mongoDb already used optimistic locking.

But if you want to use the direct command on mongoDb. Don't remember every update used optimistic locking.

we can`t know if the documents were updated before by any users without using findAndModify command.